# Generate a dynamic running total in interactive report in Apex 5

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am looking to create a running total in an interactive report in Apex 5 that re-calculates when the report is re-sorted.

I have managed to get the running total in using the following query

```
select STOCK_MOVEMENT.SKU as SKU,
    STOCK_MOVEMENT.REF as REF,
    STOCK_MOVEMENT.CUST as CUST,
    STOCK_MOVEMENT.DTE as DTE,
    STOCK_MOVEMENT.QTY as QTY,
    SUM(QTY) OVER(PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY DTE RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 
CURRENT ROW) AS RUNNING_TOTAL,
    STOCK_MOVEMENT.CREF as CREF,
    STOCK_MOVEMENT.CUAC as CUAC 
 from STOCK_MOVEMENT STOCK_MOVEMENT
 order by STOCK_MOVEMENT.SKU ASC, STOCK_MOVEMENT.DTE ASC, STOCK_MOVEMENT.CUAC ASC
```

.
When the report order is changed to customer order, for example, the running total becomes useless.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.